# how to make a button go from MainActivity page to another (Android)

Tags: android

I noticed that even though I made a new xml named drink, there is no ".java" file with it. Do I need to make one or do i add it on to MainActivity.java?

This code is in my MainActivity.java and the Intent line is saying that drink cannot be resolved to a type.

```
public void calculate(View view){
   Log.i("clicks","You Clicked B1");
   Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, drink.class);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

This is in my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".drink">
</activity>
```

This is a post before I knew android. I didn't realize you have to make the java file and xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This code is in my MainActivity.java and the Intent line is saying
>   that drink cannot be resolved to a type.

This means that you don't have a "drink" class. you have to create a new class called "drink" that extends `Activity`in the application package.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further code to go on (including knowing what your drink class and your manifest.xml looks like), I would check to make sure that the package name specified in the manifest tag of your manifest file matches the package name of your drink class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you correctly, but to go to a different 'page', which is in your case an `Activity`, you have have to create one yourself.

If you do not see a .java file representing your Activity you should make one like this (note the uppercase Drink for naming conventions):

```
public class Drink extends Activity{
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
         this.setContentView(R.layout.drink.xml)
       }
}
```

I am assuming you already made a xml file for the layout of the `Activity`. Please read the helpfull [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) of Android.

Answer (score -1):

This means that you did not create the class yet. Right - click on your package name in Package Explorer and select *Class*. Then, create your activity with your desired class name. Also, check if you declared your `android:onClick = calculate` in your XML file if you get a yellow attention sign that says that your method is not used.